# MVC How to pass label data from view to controller?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I am trying to pass data from view to controller. I used BeginForm and i can pass data which users enter to textbox. But I want to also pass label data because label is filled automatically and i need to save this label text to database. How can i do?
View:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Room", "Booking", FormMethod.Post))
{
                         <table>
                            <tr>
                                <td align="left"><lable for="eventName">Description:</lable></td>
                                <td><input name="eventName" id="eventName"></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td align="left"><lable for="startDate">Start Date : </td>
                                <td align="left"><label id="startDate" name="startDate" /></td>
                            </tr>

                            <tr>
                                <td></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td align="right" colspan="2">
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn-primary" name="submit" id="submit">Save</button>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>

                            </tr>
                        </table>
}
```

Controller:

```
 [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Room(FormCollection form)
        {

            using (BookingEntities ent = new BookingEntities ())
            {
                 ReservationTBL Tbl = new ReservationTBL();

                Tbl.Description = form["eventName"].ToString();
                Tbl.startDate= form["startDate"].ToString();

                ent.BookingTBL.Add(Tbl);
                ent.SaveChanges();
            }

            return View();
        }
```

Comment: A `<label>` is not a form control. You need to generate a form control for the value e.g. a hidden input

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The label data doesn't get send when you post your form. What you can do however is to add an input with type hidden that contains your label data.

Something like this:

```
<tr>
  <td align="left"><label for="startDate">Start Date : </td>
  <td align="left">
    <label>@Model.StartDate</label>
    <input type="hidden" name="startDate" value="@Model.StartDate" id="startDate"/>
  </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: @john update your question with code.  don't put blocks of code into comments.

Comment: Thanks for your helps :)